# "VisualTreeHelper.GetDescendantBounds()" returns Infinity

Tags: .net, wpf, visualtreehelper

Why does the `VisualTreeHelper.GetDescendantBounds(SomeVisualItem)` method return `(-Infinity,-Infinity,Infinity,Infinity)`?

The SomeVisualItem's `Canvas.Left`, `Canvas.Top`, `Width`, ... are explicitly assigned.

Comment: When do you call that? If you call that on window constructor, call it later when the visual tree is built already. eg Loaded event

Comment: Yes , i know.
I call that after visual tree built(for example:in some button click eventhandler)
Actually,i have a rectangle in canvas that the Item is in the same canvas ,and now i want to determine that the Item is in the rectangle or not.

Comment: Maybe try attaching [WPF Inspector](http://wpfinspector.codeplex.com/releases/view/62380). Maybe it gives you some hint why it happens.

Comment: Is SomeVisualItem a customer control ?

Comment: SomeVisualItem is a ContentControl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it.
just i removed Effect from a ViewBox in my control's ControlTemplate:

```
<Viewbox Opacity=".7" Stretch="Uniform" IsHitTestVisible="False" FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" IsEnabled="False" ForceCursor="False" x:Name="PART_OutThumb">
    <Viewbox.Effect>
        <BlurEffect KernelType="Gaussian" Radius="1" />
    </Viewbox.Effect>
</Viewbox>
```

To:

```
<Viewbox Opacity=".7" Stretch="Uniform" IsHitTestVisible="False" FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" IsEnabled="False" ForceCursor="False" x:Name="PART_OutThumb">
</Viewbox>
```

Now `VisualTreeHelper.GetDescendantBounds()` works well!